# Float element in an HTML page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this div element in the body of the html page:

```
<div id="alerts">
{% block alerts %}
  {% try %}
    {% if alerts is not None %}
      {% for alert in alerts %} 
        <div class="{{alert.get('level', 'alert') }}">
          {{ alert.get('content') }}
        </div>
      {% end %}
    {% end %}
  {% except NameError %}
  {% end %}
{% end %}   
</div>
```

that shows an alert or error in some situations.

But when I scroll down the page, this is not visible. How can show this element in the top of the page in relation with the scrolling of the page itself?

The css is this:

```
#alerts { 
display:none; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position:fixed` instead of `absolute` here's more info on positioning just in case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position